Explicit bounds on gaps between zeros of $\zeta^\prime(s)$
In $\S$9.1 of "Theory of the Riemann Zeta Function", Titchmarsh uses Borel-Carathéodory and Hadamard Three Circles to show that every circle of radius 6 and center $3+iT$ contains a zeros of $\zeta(s)$, and thus the gaps between ordinates of successive zeros are bounded (with an explicit bound).  (Although he does not mention it, the proof only holds for $T$ sufficiently large, but it looks like this could be made explicit with some work.)
And it looks like the proof might generalize to the zeros of $\zeta^\prime(s)$ (with different constants).  Before I go to the trouble, I'm wondering if this is already in the literature somewhere?
